# Change date value after confirmation

Tags: sharepoint-designer, date

I got a list where certain items have to be checked yearly.

What I am thinking is send to notification email a month prior to due date and when he clicks confirm, the date field should be 2020 instead of 2019.

Is it possible to do that?

Also, would it be possible to add 6 months, 1 year or 2 years based on the selection in confirmation form?

Comment: Try using sharepoint designer workflow. i guess it is best suited for your requirement.

Comment: I am using that but I don't have any idea how to change value upon confirmation

Comment: You can add year, months to date variable in workflow. Check workflow actions you will find it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this:

[image]

+1 means add one day to LastReminderTime. It works perfectly